# Formatting numbers in output to a text field

Tags: jquery

I have a text field on my html page and i want to write several contignous numbers in this field with jQuery.

Here is my text field on my HTMML Page

```
<div id="cardID" align="center"> </div>
```

Here is the code to write into the text field

```
$(#cardID').text(data.devID + '' + data.behBereich + '' + data.behZone + '-' + data.defEinheiten + '-|');
```

In the case that these variables have the following content:

```
data.devID = 10
data.behBereich = 20
data.behZone = 30
data.defEinheiten = 40
```

the output will be: 102030-40-|
now if data.devID = 5 the output will be 52030-40-|

Now my question is how can I get an output, where every variable is a two-digit output. So that the output with data.devID = 5 is like: 502030-40-|

Is there any format options for the output of the variables?

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of your variable if it is less then 2 append "0" in your variable before putting it into div

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var data={};
data.devID = 5
data.behBereich = 20
data.behZone = 30
data.defEinheiten = 40

var checkNumber=function(number){
 return (number<10? number*10:number).toString();
}

$('#cardID').text(checkNumber(data.devID) +checkNumber(data.behBereich)  +checkNumber(data.behZone) + '-' + checkNumber(data.defEinheiten) + '-|')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cardID">

</div>
```